# Using simple code to get the average (in Python) of an entire column in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I've seen similar questions, but never one that gives a simple straightforward pythonic answer.

I'm simply trying to get the average for the "high" column in a csv file.

```
import csv
import numpy as np    


with open('2010-Jan-June.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    highs = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
        high = int(row['high'])
print(sum(highs)/len(highs))
```

My csv looks like this:

```
date,high,low,precip
1-Jan,43,41,0
2-Jan,50,25,0
3-Jan,51,25,0
4-Jan,44,25,0
5-Jan,36,21,0
6-Jan,39,20,0
7-Jan,47,21,0.04
8-Jan,30,14,0
9-Jan,30,12,0
```

Comment: Change `high = int(row['high'])` to `highs.append(int(row['high']))`

Comment: Put a `def` in front of `high_avgs():`

Comment: @PaulPanzer it was actually in there.  I meant to bring the code over out of my function box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

avg = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/2010-Jan-June.csv', usecols=['high'], squeeze=True).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Note, this is totally possible using plain Python:

```
import csv
import statistics as stats

with open('2010-Jan-June.csv') as f:
    avg = stats.mean(row['high'] for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','))

print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you imported `numpy` you can use that - almost as easily as `pandas`:

Reading from a paste copy of your sample:

```
In [36]: txt="""date,high,low,precip
    ...: 1-Jan,43,41,0
    ...: 2-Jan,50,25,0
    ...: 3-Jan,51,25,0
    ...: 4-Jan,44,25,0
    ...: 5-Jan,36,21,0
    ...: 6-Jan,39,20,0
    ...: 7-Jan,47,21,0.04
    ...: 8-Jan,30,14,0
    ...: 9-Jan,30,12,0"""
```

Python3 with numpy 1.14 likes to have the `encoding` parameter:

```
In [38]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=None,names=True,
    ...: encoding=None)
In [39]: data
Out[39]: 
array([('1-Jan', 43, 41, 0.  ), ('2-Jan', 50, 25, 0.  ),
       ('3-Jan', 51, 25, 0.  ), ('4-Jan', 44, 25, 0.  ),
       ('5-Jan', 36, 21, 0.  ), ('6-Jan', 39, 20, 0.  ),
       ('7-Jan', 47, 21, 0.04), ('8-Jan', 30, 14, 0.  ),
       ('9-Jan', 30, 12, 0.  )],
      dtype=[('date', '<U5'), ('high', '<i8'), ('low', '<i8'), ('precip', '<f8')])
```

The result is a structured array, from which it is easy to pick the `high` field:

```
In [40]: data['high']
Out[40]: array([43, 50, 51, 44, 36, 39, 47, 30, 30])
In [41]: data['high'].mean()
Out[41]: 41.111111111111114
```

Or in one line, loading just one column:

```
In [44]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=[1]).mean()
Out[44]: 41.111111111111114
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a pythonic answer using just csv library...

```
import csv
with open ('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print sum(float(d['high']) for d in reader) / (reader.line_num - 1)
```

Will have a divide by 0 if there are no lines in the file.